# How to get unique ids from array loop using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following array which I am getting as mysql result set

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [slug] => block_three_column
            [title] => CSG 2
            [type_id] => 8
            [entry_id] => 6
            [stream_id] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [slug] => block_three_column
            [title] => CSG
            [type_id] => 8
            [entry_id] => 5
            [stream_id] => 11
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [slug] => block_three_column
            [title] => CSG 2
            [type_id] => 8
            [entry_id] => 6
            [stream_id] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [slug] => block_three_column
            [title] => CSG
            [type_id] => 8
            [entry_id] => 5
            [stream_id] => 11
        )

)
```

The both arrays are similar I want get the unique entry id using php.

I tried with the following code but it is producing 2 arrays again.

```
foreach($block_results as $rowarr)
{
   foreach($rowarr as $k=>$v)
   {
        if($k == "entry_id")
        {
            $entid[] = $v; 
        }

   }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

﻿

Comment: Are you saying - if the value in `entry_id` matches between the two arrays you want to add that to the `$entid` array?

Comment: Or a list of only unique `entry_id` values in each array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `entry_id` directly:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'slug' => 'block_three_column',
        'title' => 'CSG 2',
        'type_id' => 8,
        'entry_id' => 6,
        'stream_id' => 11
    ),
    array(
        'slug' => 'block_three_column',
        'title' => 'CSG',
        'type_id' => 8,
        'entry_id' => 5,
        'stream_id' => 11
    )
);

foreach ($array as $innerArray) {
    if (isset($innerArray['entry_id'])) {
        $entid[] = $innerArray['entry_id'];
    }
}

var_dump($entid);
```

Output is:

```
array
  0 => int 6
  1 => int 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map()` instead of `foreach()`. Example:

```
$entry_ids = array_unique(
    array_map(
        function($v){ 
            return $v['entry_id'];
        }, 
        $array
    )
);
var_dump($entry_ids);
```

`array_unique()` is to remove duplicate elements from `array()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want a list of the unique values of `entry_id` from the array, and it is possible that some will not have an `entry_id` set:

```
$entid = array();

foreach ( $array as $blockArray) {
    if ( isset( $blockArray['entry_id'] )
       && !in_array( $blockArray['entry_id'], $entid ) ) {
        $entid[] = $blockArray['entry_id'];
    }
}

var_dump( $entid );
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. Worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**PHP**

```
$entid = array(); //Holds unique id's
foreach($block_results as $rowarr)
{
    //Make sure entry_id exists
    $entid[] = array_key_exists('entry_id',$rowarry) ? $rowarr['entry_id'] : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are always similiar and the same length:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $firstValue = $array1[$key]['entry_id'];
    $secondValue = $array2[$key]['entry_id'];
}
```

Though, keep in mind this solution is very sensitive to errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this like your code:

```
$block_results = array(
    array(
        'slug' => 'block_three_column',
'title' => 'CSG 2',
'type_id' => 8,
'entry_id' => 6,
'stream_id' => 11
),
array(
'slug' => 'block_three_column',
'title' => 'CSG',
'type_id' => 8,
'entry_id' => 6,
'stream_id' => 11
),
array(
'slug' => 'block_three_column',
'title' => 'CSG',
'type_id' => 8,
'entry_id' => 7,
'stream_id' => 11
)
);

var_dump($block_results);
$entid=array();
if(count($block_results)>0)foreach($block_results as $rowarr)
{
    $entid[] = $rowarr['entry_id'];     
}
$entid=array_unique($entid);
var_dump($entid);
```

output:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'slug' => string 'block_three_column' (length=18)
      'title' => string 'CSG 2' (length=5)
      'type_id' => int 8
      'entry_id' => int 6
      'stream_id' => int 11
  1 => 
    array
      'slug' => string 'block_three_column' (length=18)
      'title' => string 'CSG' (length=3)
      'type_id' => int 8
      'entry_id' => int 6
      'stream_id' => int 11
  2 => 
    array
      'slug' => string 'block_three_column' (length=18)
      'title' => string 'CSG' (length=3)
      'type_id' => int 8
      'entry_id' => int 7
      'stream_id' => int 11

array
  0 => int 6
  2 => int 7
```